# Contact form :405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

So i've followed the tutorial from bootstrap snippets website, but still can't seem to get the contact form to work. I do not get the message the the form is submitted and also when i look into console i see the following message : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here IS MY PHP Code

```
<?php

$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>'


$sendTo = '<fredcsharp@gmail.com>';


$subject = 'New message from contact form';

$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Last Name', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';


$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
            
    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }


    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}



if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}

else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Here is My JS

```
$(function () {

 
 
    $('#contact-form').validator();
 
 
    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
 
        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var tigerContact = "contact/TigerContact.php";
 
            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: tigerContact,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
 
                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;
 
                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    
                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
 });
```

Comment: you forgot e.preventDefault() in your "submit" function. You must prevent the default submission or else the page will attempt a full postback of the form, instead of doing the AJAX request. I don't know how your validator works, so I'm going to assume that `if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {` is necessary, therefore you need to add `e.preventDefault()` on the line just below it. Try that and let me know the result.

Comment: if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) e.preventDefault() ? like this? If yes, i did try this and nothing has changed